# Which type of regression to use?

Tags: regression, time-series

I am still a rookie at statistics. I am writing a report on crimes and how they affect economic prosperity. I have yearly data for 30 years from  1 country, where number of crimes in a year is my independent variable and GDP growrth is my dependent variable. I have 3 other control variables as external invtment, total trade and infrastructure.

Now my key question is can I use multivariate time series? if not, which is the best regression in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Multivariate time series (ARMAX models) are a generalization of "regression models" as you know them. The ARMAX model is also sometimes called a Transfer Function model. A final model can include appropriate contemporaneous and lag structures for your pre-specified causal series and potentially both an ARIMA structure to reflect omitted stochastic series and empirically identified Pulse/Level Shift/Time Trends/Seasonal Pulses which can reflect/proxy omitted deterministic effects/series. Some data sets require either power transforms or Generalized least Squares to render an error process invariant over time.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir. Do I need to first check whether my data is stationery or non-stationery and the run the regressions?

Comment: Pleas use https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/75/ as a possible way to identify the model which will include any needed non-stationarity . There are cases where both x and y are themselves non-stationary BUT the Transfer Model does not include any differencing operators.